# Adding a variable on an input in webform

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-webform

I tried using jQuery, and it adds the title as I instruct, but it doesn't add it to the SOURCE CODE.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#ID_to_webform_input').attr('title', 'TEXT SHOWS UP AS TITLE')
});
```

I am trying to obtain something similar to what shown in this page: [Calculating Order Form Totals](http://www.mcfedries.com/JavaScript/OrderTotals.asp).

It asks me to add `onChange="CalculateTotal(this.form)"` to the inputs I want to calculate, but using jQuery in this manner is not doing the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes won't be accepted by the webform as input. Try using [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/).